# QML wrapped TableView element behaves different from non-wrapped one

Tags: c++, qt, layout, qml

I'm having some troubles getting the QML type TableView to behave correctly when wrapping it inside another item. The problem is that creating a reuseable type basically forces one to use an Item wrapper to have the *HeaderView types in the same .qml file. Here is the rather simple code, a test-model for some data can be taken from the official [TableView documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-tableview.html).

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
import TableModel

Window {  
    width: 600
    height: 480
    visible: true

    // This item wrapper changes TableView behavior
    Item {
        width: 600
        height: 250
    // --------------------------------------------

        TableView {
            id: tableView
            anchors.fill: parent
            topMargin: horizontalHeader.implicitHeight
            leftMargin: verticalHeader.implicitWidth
            columnSpacing: 1
            rowSpacing: 1
            clip: true

            model: TableModel {}

            delegate: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: 150
                implicitHeight: 25
                Text {
                    text: display
                }
            }
        }

        HorizontalHeaderView {
            id: horizontalHeader
            syncView: tableView
        }

        VerticalHeaderView {
            id: verticalHeader
            syncView: tableView
        }
    // --------------------------------------------
    }
    // --------------------------------------------
}
```

Without the Item wrapper (see comments in code) my TableView looks as expected:
[image: TableView without Item wrapper]

But once wrapped inside an Item the horizontal and vertical headers get placed over the actual table.
[image: TableView with Item wrapper]

For some odd reason this displacement is only relevant for the very first rendering of the table. Once I drag the data from the table around a little (I guess activating the "Flickable" inherited type?) the data suddenly snaps into position and is displayed correctly outside of the headers.

Comment: My guess is the implicit size of the headers that you are binding to are not properly throwing *Changed signals when they are updating. Have you tried changing those to constant values for what they end up being after the data loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it wasn't a good idea to use `anchors.fill: parent` when trying to attach the *HeaderViews. Once I got rid of that line and simply anchored all views to each other (horizontal to top, vertical to left) it works.

```
Item {  
    implicitWidth: 600
    implicitHeight: 250

    TableView {
        id: tableView
        implicitWidth: parent.implicitWidth
        implicitHeight: parent.implicitHeight
        anchors.top: horizontalHeader.bottom
        anchors.left: verticalHeader.right
        columnSpacing: 1
        rowSpacing: 1
        clip: true

        model: TableModel {}

        delegate: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 150
            implicitHeight: 25
            Text {
                text: display
            }
        }
    }

    HorizontalHeaderView {
        id: horizontalHeader
        anchors.left: verticalHeader.right
        clip: true
        syncView: tableView
    }

    VerticalHeaderView {
        id: verticalHeader
        anchors.top: horizontalHeader.bottom        
        clip: true        
        syncView: tableView
    }    
}
```

Note thougt that in the official [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-bestpractices.html#don-ts) using anchors inside layouts is explicitly listed as "Don'ts". My guess is that they mean don't use anchors between layout elements or parents of the layout, not don't anchor two elements inside a single layout cell.